# "Error Number: 1064 The Error returned was: You have an error in your SQL syntax;" при выполнении запроса на INSERT

Tags: php

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `".USERPREFIX."_users_status` (`name`, `user_status`) VALUES ('{$sql}', '{$member_id['name']}'");
```

Когда выполняю запрос выводит такую ошибку

> Error Number: 1064 The Error returned was: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке по сути всё изложено "Номер ошибки: 1064 Обнаружена ошибка: У вас ошибка в запросе, проверить документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса использовать вблизи'' в строке 1"

Т.е. в 1 строке своего фала внимательнее посмотри код

Comment: Да, согласен с ответом нижу - не хватает закрывающейся скобы - )

Место сами поищите по логике (у Вас 3 открывающиеся скобки "(" и 2 закрывающиеся ")")

Answer (score 1):

Вроде закрывающей ) в конце не хватает